# [XX000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Parsed manifest is not a valid JSON object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I'm running a crawler over a folder containing several files with different schemas. I expect so to find a table for each file.

What happens is that in the Glue Catalogue I can actually see a table for each file, with its own schema. But when I try to query it via Redshift Spectrum (after creating the external schema etc.) I get this exception:

```
[XX000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Parsed manifest is not a valid JSON object.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

**For Googlers:**

Crawler set `Location` of a Glue table to a file if it cannot make a table out of its containing folder.

That is, the file:

- is not in a folder but directly in root path of a bucket
- does not have a file format, compression method or schema that is compatible with sibling files in the same folder

A `Location` pointing directly at a file is not supported by Redshift Spectrum or Athena, thus this error.

To solve this problem, make a containing folder, also make sure all siblings have same format. Run the crawler again.

You should then see `Location` pointing to a prefix in a bucket.

Comment: THANK YOU! I was stuck on this for so long haha. A direct path works for ingestion, but not Spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

As reported in this forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=266510

> every file should be in its own folder/sub-bucket

So for me putting each file in its own folder and setting the Glue Crawler to run over the top level folder resolved the exception.

I'm now able to query it without any problem.

Comment: FYI that link doesn't work anymore

Comment: @DixieFlatline I see thanks. Than it's good I reported here that solution

Comment: @Vzzarr you should make the other answer the approved answer.