# Grabbing a particular value from a json type in sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have these varies entries in a column that look like this

```
[{'bus': '008', 'device': '002', 'bDeviceClass': '0 (Defined at Interface level)',  'iSerial': '3 30J155001549',... }]
```

I want to grab the `iSerial` value `30J155001549` but I am not sure exactly how to do this in sql. Any recommendations are greatly appreciated. The database we are using is Redshift.

I have tried this

```
SELECT json_extract_path_text(
    json_extract_array_element_text(device_usb,0), 'iSerial'
)
FROM table
LIMIT 1;
```

But I am getting this error

```
[XX000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: JSON parsing error Details: ----------------------------------------------- error: JSON parsing er ...
```

Here is a full example

```
[{'bus': '004', 'device': '002', 'bDeviceClass': '0 (Defined at Interface level)', 'bInterfaceClass': '3 Human Interface Device', 'bInterfaceProtocol': '2 Mouse', 'idVendor': '0x413c Dell Computer Corp.', 'idProduct': '0x301a', 'iManufacturer': '1 PixArt', 'iProduct': '2 Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse', 'iSerial': '0', 'MaxPower': '100mA'}, {'bus': '003', 'device': '014', 'bDeviceClass': '224 Wireless', 'bInterfaceClass': '224 Wireless', 'bInterfaceProtocol': '1 Bluetooth', 'idVendor': '0x8087 Intel Corp.', 'idProduct': '0x07dc', 'iManufacturer': '0', 'iProduct': '0', 'iSerial': '0', 'MaxPower': '100mA'}, {'bus': '003', 'device': '010', 'bDeviceClass': '0 (Defined at Interface level)', 'bInterfaceClass': '3 Human Interface Device', 'bInterfaceProtocol': '0 None', 'idVendor': '0x413c Dell Computer Corp.', 'idProduct': '0x2113', 'iManufacturer': '0', 'iProduct': '2 Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard', 'iSerial': '0', 'MaxPower': '100mA'}, {'bus': '005', 'device': '002', 'bDeviceClass': '0 (Defined at Interface level)', 'bInterfaceClass': '3 Human Interface Device', 'bInterfaceProtocol': '0 None', 'idVendor': '0x0c2e Metro', 'idProduct': '0x09cf', 'iManufacturer': '1 Honeywell Imaging & Mobility', 'iProduct': '2 CCB02', 'iSerial': '8 16197B4974', 'MaxPower': '500mA'}]
```

Comment: When asking SQL question, please always __provide the DBMS__ (database and version), e.g. as tags. The functions (for JSON) depend heavily on the database-system you are using.

Comment: @hc_dev Just revised to include database

Comment: We require you to add a [example] showing your attempted code. I assume you are new to _SQL_ and _Amazon Redshift_ so I provided a little kick-start answer. But please, next time, do the research on the docs prior to asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Research the database's documentation for SQL functions

See the reference-documentation of *Amazon Redshift* SQL about [JSON functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html):

> **json_extract_path_text**('json_string', 'path_elem' [,'path_elem'[, …] ] [, null_if_invalid ] )

This function can be applied to extract a field as text. You have two pass 2 arguments:

- the *field* with your JSON-content (1st parameter)
- the JSN-path as string (2nd parameter)

#### Applied

Something like:

```sql
SELECT
json_extract_path_text(
    json_extract_array_element_text(jsonContainingField,0), 'iSerial'
)
FROM table
```

assumed to give you the column name `iSerial` from the first (`0` since the index is zero-based!) element of your given *array*. If the column contains below **JSON in valid format**, then the result should be as expected: `3 30J155001549`

```json
[
  {
    'bus': '008', 
    'device': '002', 
    'bDeviceClass': '0 (Defined at Interface level)',
    'iSerial': '3 30J155001549'
   }
]
```

#### Troubleshooting: JSON parse error

The error-message you got seems to indicate that the JSON passed to the function (or the contents of the column) is no valid JSON.

See similar: [[XX000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Parsed manifest is not a valid JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62278504/xx000500310-amazon500310-invalid-operation-parsed-manifest-is-not-a-val#62278505)

Did you try a dry-run by passing a constant JSON-string to the function like in the official doc's JSON-function examples?

As far as I know valid JSON requires fields and text-values to be enclosed in **double quotes** like `"fieldName": "textValue"` instead of `'fieldName': 'textValue'`.

#### Validate JSON prior

You can check each JSON with some free tools on your computer on the web. For example [JsonLint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) reports the given JSON as **invalid**!

#### Validate JSON in Redshift

Use the [IS_VALID_JSON](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/IS_VALID_JSON.html) function to check which rows contain invalid JSON, like `SELECT device_usb, IS_VALID_JSON(device_usb) FROM table`.

For each invalid results (where `false` is returned), you can then try to update the value by using an UPDATE statement with the suitable text- or [String-functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/String_functions_header.html).

Example:

```sql
UPDATE table SET device_usb = TRANSLATE(device_usb, ''', '"') WHERE IS_VALID_JSON(device_usb) = 'false'
```

#### Invalid: single quotes

```json
[{
    'bus': '004'
}]
```

A slight replacement of all single-quotes `'` by required double-quotes `"` made it valid.

##### Valid: double quotes

```json
[{
    "bus": "004"
}]
```

Comment: @justanewb: Your JSON is simply not valid. See my updated answer. You should make sure that input/JSON is validated before inserted into the DB. Otherwise the only repair-mechanism would be to use an UPDATE with a SQL _replace-function_ to correct all invalid JSON values (replace single-quotes by double-quotes).

Comment: Yea your right its not valid, I did not insert it. It was done my someone else. I don't see your update or have tried it and still did not work

Comment: @justanewb ... my "update" is just a  solution as hint for self-help ... not a copy-paste-ready solution to your problem. Note: Stackoverflow is not a free coding-service ️

Comment: Rest is left to you: ️ search the Redshift docs for a char or CHR function to get the character you want to replace. The [single-quote](https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/single-quote-apostrophe-ascii-code-39.html) or apostroph has ASCII-code number `39`. This needs to be replaced by ASCII-code number `34` (double-quote)

Answer (score -1):

You can extract JSON by:

select * from OPENJSON('your JSON string')

Comment: What makes you assume the SQL function OPENJSON() will work on the given database? Take the chance to provide a solution based on the meanwhile given DBMS.

Comment: @hc_dev Actually when I posted answer, no DBMS was specified on question, and I had SQL Server SSMS opened on my screen. (In case you're real want to know the answer). :-)

Comment: @hc_dev Thanks for positive response. I'll work on this topic. Usually I'm fixing JSON before it's go to SQL, by one of common programming languages (C#, Python etc.).